# How do I install the mysql2 gem on ubuntu, when I'm using rails3 via rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I'm trying to figure my way around the vastly complex maze that is rails configuration. So far, I'm managed to set up rvm on ubuntu (for some reason, ruby is outdated in the ubuntu repo's).
I've managed to set up a rails project. I want my test project to use mysql rather then mysqlite.

When I tried 'rake db:migrate', I got an error:
"!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'"

When I try 'gem install mysql', I get an error, telling me that I need to provide parameters to the installation command. However, the list of parameters is huge, and I have no idea which ones to select.

How can I get rails3 via rvm running on ubuntu with mysql ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, all you need to do is to install the libmysqlclient-dev first.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

First, you need mysql installed.  You can install it using Ubuntu's package manager.  No special steps needed.  You also need to initially create your database and user using the mysql tool.  This link shows how to do that:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm

Second, you need to have the mysql2 gem listed in your Gemfile.  This tells Rails to go ahead and use that gem.  You need a line like this:

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

I'm specifying the version to be less than 0.3 because I'm using Rails 3.0.7 and version 0.3 and higher are for Rails 3.1.  Also, be sure to use the mysql2 gem and not mysql - it seems to handle character encoding better.

Third, run "bundle install" so Rails downloads and installs the mysql2 gem.

Lastly, you need to change your database.yml file to put in the connection information for your database like so:

```
development:
  adapter:  mysql2
  database: your_database_name
  username: your_username
  password: your_password
  encoding: utf8
```

The encoding part is just what I'm using, you may need something different.  This entry tells Rails how to find your database in the development environment.

Once that's all in place, things should work.

Comment: I have mysql installed, and I have the mysql2 gem listed in my gemfile. I've actually completely given up on this one, and removed my rvm installation. It's too hard for me. Ruby on ubuntu just seems to be to difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

If the above command does not work because `libmysql-ruby` cannot be found, the following should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

On Red Hat/CentOS and other distributions using yum:

```
sudo yum install mysql-devel
```

On Mac OS X with Homebrew:

```
brew install mysql
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

to install to gems as listed in gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add gem name to your Gemfile, located in your projects root:

It should read something like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', version
gem 'mysql', version
```

Where version is the the gem version you'd like to install, and will have a bunch of other information by default.

Then, navigate to your project directory and run the bundle command and you should be set.

Comment: Doing this produces the same error that I got before, only surrounded by more text. It's the same issue: the mysql or mysql2 gem needs to be given options to be installed, but the error code doesn't tell me which options it needs or why. Again - the issue seems to be specific to installing rails using rvm